# Draupadi's connections with Sri Krsna and Agni Dev?

Tags: mahabharata, goddess, agni

Goddess Draupadi-Panchali is sometimes referred to as Krsnaa, and sometimes as Agniputri or Agnijoytsna. Does this mean she has some sort of family or karmic connection with Sri Krsna and/or Agni Dev? What is her relation to these deities?

(I can understand the title of Agniputri since the Mahabharat in Adi Parvan states that she and were born out of Drupad's yajna, but do the texts bring anything more explicit about this?)

Comment: Krsnaa is the appellation given to Draupadi on account of her dark complexion and highly attractive features.